# Open Iframe content links in new window

Tags: iframe, hyperlink

I have a task where:

I have a frame which contains some external url content.
This externale content has a list of several links to some articles.
My task is to open each of these links in a seperate window, when clicked.

My code is something similar to this:

I want to open each of the links within ibnlive to open in a new window, instead of the same window.

Could anyone please help or suggest me on this, or please do suggest alternatives if there are any

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

Comment: My code is something similar to this:

<html> <body> <iframe src="http://ibnlive.in.com/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1085" height="1080" style="position:absolute;clip:rect(38%,90%,62%,28%);top:-170px; left:-120px;"></iframe> </body> </html>

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `target="_blank"` in your `<a>` tag

It should look like this:

```
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">Here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have some external content in an Iframe area, which is a list of some article links. On click of each of these embedded links, it should open up in a new window. Is this possible, or please do suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You can add target="_blank" on the links you want to open in new window

For example

```
<a href="yourlink" target="_blank">asd</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have some external content in an iframe area, which has a list of some article links. 
On click of each of these embedded links, it should open up in a new window. Is this possible, or please do suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using target="_blank" use target="_parent"

```
<a href="yourlink" target="_parent">Link</a>
```